# How to change multiple objects inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

This is a two part question that I can't seem to solve. Part one requires that the entire object belonging to 'Theo' is removed somehow.  Part two needs the object changed by editing one of the properties values belonging to 'Lorie'.  Here's the array and instructions:

```
var employees = [{
    "firstName": "Von",
    "lastName": "Budibent",
    "email": "vbudibent0@163.com",
    "department": "Sales"
}, {
    "firstName": "Catherina",
    "lastName": "Swalowe",
    "email": "cswalowe1@example.com",
    "department": "Engineering"
}, {
    "firstName": "Theo",
    "lastName": "Trill",
    "email": "ttrill2@sina.com.cn",
    "department": "Services"
}, {
    "firstName": "Elsy",
    "lastName": "McCrorie",
    "email": "emccrorie3@netscape.com",
    "department": "Legal"
}, {
    "firstName": "Lorie",
    "lastName": "Handsheart",
    "email": "lhandsheart4@fotki.com",
    "department": "Research and Development"
}]

/* Create a function called 'employeeUpdater'. employeeUpdater will loop 
over the array above and perform the following:
  1. If employee's first name is Theo, remove that employee because he just 
got fired.
  2. If the employee's first name is Lorie, change her department to 'HR'.
  3. Return the updated employee array. */
```

All I have to start is the following:

```
var employeeUpdater = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i] = 'Theo') {
      employees.remove(employees[i]);
    } else if (employees[i] = 'Lorie') {
      employees.department = 'HR';
    }
  } return employees;
}
```

Something is wrong with the code

Comment: The condition `employees[i] = 'Theo'`. This will assign the value, you need `==` or `===` to compare the values.

Comment: `employees = employees.filter(e => e.firstName !== 'Theo');
employees.find(e => e.firstName === 'Lorie').department = 'HR';`.

Comment: Looks like homework.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript arrays don't have an method with name `remove`, instead you need to use [**Array#splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method for removing an item. But I can suggest this solution.

First use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to exclude the objects with name `Theo` then use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the arrays an find the objects which name with `Lorie` and change it's department a.

```js
var employees = [{
    "firstName": "Von",
    "lastName": "Budibent",
    "email": "vbudibent0@163.com",
    "department": "Sales"
}, {
    "firstName": "Catherina",
    "lastName": "Swalowe",
    "email": "cswalowe1@example.com",
    "department": "Engineering"
}, {
    "firstName": "Theo",
    "lastName": "Trill",
    "email": "ttrill2@sina.com.cn",
    "department": "Services"
}, {
    "firstName": "Elsy",
    "lastName": "McCrorie",
    "email": "emccrorie3@netscape.com",
    "department": "Legal"
}, {
    "firstName": "Lorie",
    "lastName": "Handsheart",
    "email": "lhandsheart4@fotki.com",
    "department": "Research and Development"
}];

var editedEmployees = employees
.filter(emp => emp.firstName !== 'Theo')
.map(emp =>       
     ({
        "firstName": emp.firstName,
        "lastName": emp.lastName,
        "email": emp.email,
        "department": emp.firstName === 'Lorie' ? 'HR' : emp.department
     }));

console.log(editedEmployees)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with splice():

```
var employeeUpdater = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i].firstName == 'Theo') {
      employees.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    } else if (employees[i].firstName == 'Lorie') {
      employees[i].department = 'HR';
    }
  }
}return employees;
```

Comment: your operator should be "==="

Answer (score 0):

One of the tricky things about referencing objects in arrays is that you need to remember you have to reference them with the array index number and then the object name like employees[2].firstName would be how you reference Theo.
Also, the splice method is best for removing an array as stated above.

I believe the code you were trying to write would look like this:

```
var employeeUpdater = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i].firstName === 'Theo') {
      employees.splice(i, 1);
    } else if (employees[i].firstName === 'Lorie') {
      employees[i].department = 'HR';
    }
  } return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to program in an Object Oriented manner. Perhaps this will help:

```js
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // change pre var name if using technique on other pages

var employees = [{
  firstName:'Von',
  lastName: 'Budibent',
  email:'vbudibent0@163.com',
  department:'Sales'
}, {
  firstName:'Catherina',
  lastName:'Swalowe',
  email:'cswalowe1@example.com',
  department:'Engineering'
}, {
  firstName:'Theo',
  lastName:'Trill',
  email:'ttrill2@sina.com.cn',
  department:'Services'
}, {
  firstName:'Elsy',
  lastName:'McCrorie',
  email:'emccrorie3@netscape.com',
  department:'Legal'
}, {
  firstName:'Lorie',
  lastName:'Handsheart',
  email:'lhandsheart4@fotki.com',
  department:'Research and Development'
}];
function EmployeeHandler(employeeArray){
  this.employees = employeeArray;
  this.removeByFirstName = function(firstName, caseSensitive){
    var emp = this.employees;
    var rx = caseSensitive ? new RegExp(firstName) : new RegExp(firstName, 'i');
    for(var i=0,l=emp.length; i<l; i++){
      if(emp[i].firstName.match(rx)){
        this.employees.splice(i, 1);
        return this;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.removeByLastName = function(lastName, caseSensitive){
    var emp = this.employees;
    var rx = caseSensitive ? new RegExp(lastName) : new RegExp(lastName, 'i');
    for(var i=0,l=emp.length; i<l; i++){
      if(emp[i].lastName.match(rx)){
        this.employees.splice(i, 1);
        return this;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.getByFirstName = function(firstName, caseSensitive){
    var emp = this.employees;
    var rx = caseSensitive ? new RegExp(firstName) : new RegExp(firstName, 'i');
    for(var i=0,l=emp.length,em; i<l; i++){
      em = emp[i];
      if(em.firstName.match(rx)){
        return em;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.getByLastName = function(lastName, caseSensitive){
    var emp = this.employees;
    var rx = caseSensitive ? new RegExp(lastName) : new RegExp(lastName, 'i');
    for(var i=0,l=emp.length,em; i<l; i++){
      em = emp[i];
      if(em.lastName.match(rx)){
        return em;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

var eh = new EmployeeHandler(employees);
var bb = eh.removeByFirstName('Theo').getByLastName('Budibent');
bb.department = 'Intelligent Design';
console.log(eh.employees); console.log(bb); console.log(eh.employees);

}
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var editedEmployees = employees
.filter(emp => emp.firstName !== 'Theo')
.map((emp) => {emp.department = emp.firstName === 'Lorie' ? 'HR' : 
emp.department; return emp;});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to work with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) you can make your code easier to read.

So your script should become like this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
/* Remove element */
_.remove(employees, function (employee) { return employee.firstName === 'Theo'; });
/* Get element to change */
var employee = _.find(employees,function (employee) { return employee.firstName === 'Lorie'; });
/* Change element */
employee.firstName = 'HR';
/* Right now employees store the right result */
```